# php - Validate timestamp stored in the database with the current time if passed 24 hours

Tags: php, validation, date, datetime, time

The title says it all.. I am not sure what is wrong with my code.. But it didn't go well as i want to

```
<?php
//test this
$query = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM changepass_req WHERE reqid = 1");
$reqdate = odbc_result($query, 'req_date');
$reqdatex = strtotime($reqdate);
$timenow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $timenowx = strtotime($timenow);

    if($timenowx <= $reqdatex + 86400) {
    //Less than 24 hours
    echo'Go a head, its not a day passed yet';
    }
    else {
    //More than 24 hours
echo'Sorry, this request is expired!';
    }

?>
```

The `req_date` that's in the database is in varchar of datatype. Thanks for the help in advance

EDIT : ALSO the req_date data's are in this format (Y-m-d H:i:s)

EDIT 2 : The return of var_dump($reqdatexx) looked like this in my page : `int(1370855859)`

EDIT 3 : Here's the concept i want..
    If Database time is before OR WITHIN 24 hours of the CURRENT TIME = return true
    ELSE // if the Database time is BEYOND or PASSED 24 hours of the CURRENT TIME
    = return false

or , 
  if Database time  = 2013 6/8 5:02pm AND Current time = 2013 6/9 5:01pm      = return TRUE
   else 
   //Database time = 2013 g/6 5:02pm AND Current time = 2013 6/9 5:03pm 
   = return FALSE

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate what your question is?

Comment: obviously my code isn't correct and looking for a solution.

Comment: Well, what isn't correct, what doesn't work? What result(s) are you getting? What value is `reqdatex`?

Comment: i changed my req_date to a day advanced. Then run this again. but still it says that it doesn't passed 24 hours yet.

Comment: i evene made it 2 days advanced.

Comment: what database are you using and what is the value of $reqdate returned ?

Comment: 1. var_dump($reqdatex) after $reqdatex = strtotime($reqdate); 2. You can get the current timestamp with $timenowx = time(); Now need to convert from string.

Comment: its like, if the time the page loaded is passed 24 hours the timestamp stored in the database, then it should say that it already passed a day. otherwise not.

Comment: @user4035 you mean  $reqdatex = strtotime($reqdate);
                 var_dump($reqdatex); ? it gave me weird stuff

Comment: what is the value of var_dump($reqdate); (add to question please)?

Comment: @IanKenney i am using mssql and the $reqdate returns like this : `2013-06-10 02:17:39`

Comment: @IanKenney refer to my question to see the value for var_dump($reqdate)

Comment: Is the system time correct in both your database server and your application server?

Comment: if you mean the database server and app server(web server), yes they are. they are run'ed in a same node.

Comment: Does your database support any date functions? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE req_date >= DATE_SUB('{$todays_datestamp}' INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: @Dale there is a datatype of datetime on mssql 2008 but i don't know how to switch its format, cause it gives me Y-m-d H:i:s.ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check, that $reqdatex is inside +-24 hours interval from now, use this condition:

```
<?php

//Mon, 10 Jun 2013 09:17:39 GMT
$reqdatex = 1370855859;
$timenowx = time();

if(($reqdatex <= $timenowx + 86400) and ($reqdatex >= $timenowx - 86400)) {
    //$reqdatex is inside now +- 24 hours interval
    echo'Go ahead';
}
else {
    //not inside the interval
    echo'Sorry';
}
```

Comment: in my database, the value is '2013-06-08 02:17:39' and run the exact code i posted in this question. And it printed the true return, which is Go ahead, .. .. But when i changed it to '2013-06-10 02:!7:39' it still gives me the same value. should i convert it instead before i insert it into the database?

Comment: you guys were refering 24h into the past.

Comment: It is supposed to print the true return for the future date. No, don't convert it - it's dangerous to change the database structure. Just try 2013-05-08 02:17:39 - date in the past.

Comment: it worked when i set it in the past. But what if the page was run'ed 24hours after the timestamp posted in the database? What i want is to return false if the page was loaded AFTER 24 hours the timestamp in the database.

Comment: please refer to my question edit on the concept i really want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am not sure what is exactly you wanted, but to me it seems like you are comparing  time now to second.$timenow will return current date and time in following format.

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
    -> '2007-12-15 23:50:26'
mysql> SELECT NOW() + 0;
    -> 20071215235026.000000
```

I suggest you do the following.

Test if they are in the same date, if they are echo sorry

If not then 
Use the function datediff

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31');
    -> -31
```

If it is greater than 1 then you have more than 24 hour, if it is 1 then to be safe just strip the time part from both the date using extract and then compare if the current time is greater in that case you will have more than 24 hour.

Example:
    mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30 22:50:50');
        -> 1

In here it return 1 though it is not 24 hour so compare 23:59:59 and 22:50:50 as 22:50:50 is smaller it is not 24 hour but if we have

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 21:59:59','2007-12-30 22:50:50');
    -> 1
```

In here compare 21:59:59 and 22:50:50. As 22:50:50 is greater we have more than 24 hour.

Please read this for details
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html